# Preserving a Folder when Deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I deploy my asp.net app using VS 2015 and the AWS toolkit, it always clears out the wwwroot folder and re-uploads all files.  I want to store user uploaded supporting documents to a folder underneath wwwroot but deployment wipes them out.  Is there a way to preserve this folder and it's sub-folders?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Are these documents "business critical"? Meaning, assuming you solve your problem, is it OK if these files are deleted when your EC2 instance is terminated and re-created?

Comment: It's not ok for these documents to be deleted.  They are supporting documents that the user uploads and attaches to certain data.  I have to be able to show them to the user when they click on them, i.e. create a link to each document.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you solve the deployment issue, your bigger issue will be preserving the files if Auto Scaling decides to terminate your EC2 instances.

You should not store persistent data locally on the EC2 instance when the instance is controlled by Auto Scaling (which AWS Elastic Beanstalk uses).

Instead, you should store all persistent data off the instance. Use a service such as Amazon S3 to store data that needs to be stored beyond the lifetime of your EC2 instances.